# No jquery command is executed on page

Tags: jquery

I need to do some work with Jquery and any code that I add to the page does not work . I even tried to get some sample code from other websites but none of them works.
I checked for the jquery plugin and it loads correctly . does anyone know how to solve this .
The firebug console shows some errors , is that a problem ?
[image]

Comment: Make sure that the code you're trying to execute comes  after the inclusion of jquery

Comment: Can you tell us where are you writing the code? or can you share the link of your web page if it's public?

Comment: The error says that you haven't include jQuery correct.

Comment: thank you @ImmortalDude the code have to be after the inclusion of jquery

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#pp').text('hello world');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="pp"> </div>
```

to recall jquery you use the $ (the dollar) and inside you use the CSS selector.

Comment: How does this answer the OP question/Problem?

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @ImmortalDude the code have to be after the inclusion of jquery